# setting the size of navigationbar icon ios

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem

I want to know is there any default size for Navigationbar icons.where designer need to design it.Should they design it for retina and non-retina display.At present I'm using images downloaded from internet which are not looking great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create navigation bar icon in the following sizes:

```
About 44 x 44 pixels

About 22 x 22 pixels (standard resolution)
```

more informtation you can find here
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/BarIcons.html

Comment: what should be the bar button size to look like default

Comment: it should be max 44 x 44 for retina devices or 22 X 22 for non retina device

Comment: And now we need 66 x 66 pixels @3x image too. for new iPhones 6.

Answer (score 8):

The recommend sizes in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/) for the navigation bar icons are as follows:

```
@1: 25 x 25
@2: 50 x 50
@3: 75 x 75
```

Create three images of the above pixel sizes and then add them to a new image set in your Assets.xcassets file.

[image]

**Notes**

- When I try to make the icons at the recommended sizes, they look too small to me. I actually make them a little bigger than that. So take the doc recommendations as a starting point, but you might have to make adjustments as necessary.
- A second method would be to use a single universal vector image (pdf) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818845/how-do-vector-images-work-in-xcode-6-i-e-pdf-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149785/xcode-6-allows-vector-image-assets-any-idea-how-to-use-them)). [Not everyone recommends this](https://bjango.com/articles/idontusepdfs/), but it is the method I use now. It's convenient and makes future image editing and resizing easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. iPhone 5     88 / 64  px
 2. iPhone 4/4S  88 / 64 px 
 3. Retina iPad  88 px
 4. iPad Mini    44 px
 5. iPad         44 px
```

The Navigation Bar usually includes a title as well as basic navigation and action buttons (such as back to previous view, create, edit, etc.). In landscape orientation, the height of the Nav bar is usually shrunk a bit (to 32pt) to allow more content to be displayed below it.

Ref Link: http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

Check Apple's documentation for icon and image sizes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1). For more detailed UI icon specification check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21-SW1).