# PDF image format not working in iOS using swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set pdf image in my app tab bar, But unfortunately its not working for me .In project i am calling image like this -
 cntrl.tabBarItem.image  = UIImage.init(named: "two")

[image]

This is how i added pdf image in my xcode project

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find any name with "Scale Factor" in attribute inspector, My Xcode version is "Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)" .

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590776/xcode-8-import-pdf-vector-intro-image-assets-not-working-well

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Just now i found if i set "Render as" to "Original Image" then i can see my image but the problem is the image is in white background and tint color is black

Comment: whats your image size

Comment: Image size - 25 * 25 PDF

Comment: reduce the size as 18 * 18 and check once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik finally it works, after changing pdf image background to transparent

Comment: @great work , add the answer it will be iseful in future

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works, after changing pdf image background to transparent

Comment: but did not work for me

Comment: any clue to make it work ?