# How to use ttf / SVG icons in ios SWIFT 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, svg, icons, truetype

As in android, they can use any vector image formats. My designer gave my abc.ttf file which contains icons for the app. The interesting thing about TTF is, it is not stretched or pixelate while increasing the size. So plz help me to figure out, is there any way to use TTF or any other vector image format.
Thnks

Comment: Why -1, is it wrong to ask question that, how to use ttf icon. I implemented my own. And yes it is possible to use ttf icons. I'll post my solution after complete this project.

Comment: Can you please post solution for using ttf files for images?

Comment: @Abha This weekend

Comment: @Abha  I know this late but you can check it here : https://medium.com/@deerchaudhary/svg-or-ttf-icons-in-ios-swift-4-0-without-using-any-third-party-library-4622deaf0939

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted my solution at medium.

Refer [SVG or TTF icons in iOS (Swift 4.0) without using any third party library.](https://medium.com/@deerchaudhary/svg-or-ttf-icons-in-ios-swift-4-0-without-using-any-third-party-library-4622deaf0939)

**Step 1:** Get your ttf file from the designer or get it online. I am showing with fontAwesome icons.

Link where you get ttf file. : https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/

Download this and extract it. You will see the fonts folder in it. Go to fontawesome-webfont.ttf.

**Step 2:** Open this TTF file and install
[image]

After Installation
[image: Installed icons file]

**Step 3:** Open to your iOS project, go to your storyboard/Xib file add an UILabel.

**Step 4:** Add/import TTF file (downloaded) to your project.

**Step 5:** Now in your attribute inspector, go fonts and choose custom and click on family, you will see a list of fonts.

[image]

Choose FontAwesome (or you ttf file name).

That is so easy man. :P

Wait your last step is remaining.

**Step 6:**  (Last One): Open your font file, select icon which you want to use and copy it.

[image]

Paste in the text area of your UILable in your storyboard/Xib.

You can use any icon from this file and there is plenty of icons already available at https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet?from=io. You just need to copy and paste in the text of your label.

Step 1, 2 and 3 are a one-time process for a project and if you want to use the same TTF file in another project as well skip step 1 and 2.

The same procedure goes with buttons.

Comment: Unfortunately, your medium link is not working! Can you please update?

Comment: @AshishKakkad now you can check

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector PDFs instead of images

Refer [How to use vectors in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25818846/360513)