# Can I use SVG files in Xcode projects?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have downloaded "Add-to-Apple-Wallet" button from Apple website. But the format given is SVG.

The guidelines says that I should not modify the image. Should I use the SVG as it is in the project or can I convert it to pdf or png using some tool like sketch.

Comment: is there any pblm u facing

Comment: People suggested that SVG is not natively supported in iOS and suggested to convert svg to pdf. Neither i could find any official link that talks about this. my app supports from iOS 8 and worried about performance on lower devices.

Comment: It is not a big deal, just convert it to PNG and add it to the default imageset you have.

Comment: Xcode converts vector graphics to png at compile time. A few years ago Xcode supported only pdf, not svg, but since the download gives you svg, I'd try using it first. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25818846/335858) for details.

Answer (score 9):

Starting from Xcode 12 SVG support was added in xcassets file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options for displaying svg images on iPhone:

The iOS Browser actually renders SVG:

```
let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Add_to_Apple_Wallet_rgb_HB", ofType: "svg")!)
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest.init(url: url) as URLRequest)
```

Or you can use a third party library:

[SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) The most complete, supports multi path svg's.

[PocketSVG](https://github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG) Good, storyboard compatible, but you can only load single path svg's.