# PDF image for iOS Assets

Tags: ios, xcode8, assets

we can add image as pdf in ios assets for application.But i'm confusing that which approach is good for application.

- Png file direct drag and drop to Assets
- or use image as PDF

i have follows links
https://icons8.com/articles/how-to-use-vectors-in-xcode-7/
and https://bjango.com/articles/idontusepdfs/
but not able to decide which one is better solution for assets.
 i know how to works with pdf asset but cannot decide which method is better from development point of view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do vector images work in Xcode (i.e. pdf files)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818845/how-do-vector-images-work-in-xcode-i-e-pdf-files)

Comment: @Er.Khatri, i know how to works with pdf asset. but my question is Which approach is better from point of development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your artwork has complex gradients, generate the PNGs yourself. Otherwise, use PDFs. That's how I read it.

Personally, I have the luxury of working with a designer who just gives me assets at all the required sizes. On another project, Sketch was used which can auto-generate PNGs from a script as part of the build process. So I've never actually used PDFs.

Comment: so, i should use pdf for app icons and for reset of image should i use pngs? i have no complex gradients.

Comment: If you don't have complex gradients, I'd try and use PDFs for everything.