# iOS - pros and cons of using vector asset than png

Tags: ios, xcode

In my recent project, our team had decided using vector image asset with pdf format. 
What pros and cons of using vector than normal png?

If I have three different image size for one image, 30x30, 75x75, 123x123. In this case, will Xcode generate all of them? Or generate only one png?

If I set a "Preserve vector data" option and using single scale, does iOS generate png images on runtime? Does it works with dynamic size view?

Comment: found someone's opinion here: https://www.quora.com/Should-you-use-SVG-files-for-images-in-an-iOS-native-app.   how xcode works with vector assets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818845/how-do-vector-images-work-in-xcode-i-e-pdf-files/25818846#25818846