# What are the image formats supported by UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uikit

What are the image file formats supported by UIImage?

I managed to find this documentation page but is is quite old and outdated I assume since it does not even include PDF.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/LoadingImages/LoadingImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH17-SW7

Answer (score 2):

Actually the `UIImage` itself should have no direct correlation to formats you are looking for and you will need to add more context. `UIImage` is just a representation of raw pixel data such as 32bit RGBA.

A more contextual question would be; what are supported formats to initialize `UIImage` by using `init(contentsOfFile:)` method which is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624112-init). Unfortunately even this part seems to lack documentation for what formats it supports though.

In parent documentation I can only see mentioning of PNG and JPEG formats. And trying to initialize it with a pdf actually results as a fail and returns `nil`.

But then on the other hand pdf is supported in assets which is a completely different thing. Quickly inspecting web I can find no proper documentation from Apple about it (Though I assume it must be somewhere) but there is this very nice [post about it you should read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25818846/526828). Basically it states that PDFs are actually converted to PNGs at build time.

So perhaps the information you posted is not outdated at all.

Comment: Thank you for answer. 

There is a flag in inspector when you choose the PDF resource: "Preserve Vector Data".

I don't know how it is handled but it is not converted to PNG at build time if you enable that.